# Adding Columns to DataTable Cuts of Last Column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

I am building a DataTable From a SQL Query in `vb.net`

Once I have the DataTable Filled using

```vb
' Build DataTable to Store Result
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
' Fill DataTable From SQL Query
da.Fill(dt)
```

I am adding two Columns That are Merging Some of the Data Such as the First and Last Name

```vb
' Merge Columns
dt.Columns.Add("RECIPIENT", GetType(String)).SetOrdinal(0)
dt.Columns.Add("PURCHASER", GetType(String)).SetOrdinal(1)
For Each Row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Row("RECIPIENT") = String.Format("{0} {1}", Trim(Row("INSURED_FIRST_NAME")), Trim(Row("INSURED_LAST_NAME")))
    Row("PURCHASER") = String.Format("{0} {1}", Trim(Row("PAYOR_FIRST_NAME")), Trim(Row("PAYOR_LAST_NAME")))
Next
```

Lastly, I am using a `DataGridView` to display the content on the form. However, it appears that the `DAtaGridView` is cutting off the last Column when I do this.

```vb
' Add DataTable as DataSource and Auto Generate Columns
dgvContent.DataSource = Records
dgvContent.AutoGenerateColumns = True
```

So for example, if my columns `ID`, `INSURED_FIRST_NAME`, `INSURED_LAST_NAME`, `PAYOR_FIRST_NAME`, `PAYOR_LAST_NAME`, `TOTAL_COST`

Once I set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `true`, it will create a column header for all fields except for whichever is last, in this instance `TOTAL_COST`

Why is this happening and is there a better way to resolve it other than

```vb
' Add Blank Column to DataTable so `AutoGenerateColumns` Generates All Visible Columns Correctly
dt.Columns.Add("BLANK", GetType(String))
```

Comment: Should this be dt instead of Records? dgvContent.DataSource = Records

Comment: Yes and no, I left out that the `DataTable` is Generated in a Background Worker and the `DataGridView` is filled in the `RunWorkerCompleted`. On `RunWorkerCompleted` I set a Variable called `Records` to `e.Result` which is the `Datatable` from Background Worker `DoWork` Event

Comment: There is no compete method where you can send an object.  You can use ReportProgress which does have an object you can pass.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
' Build DataTable to Store Result
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
' Fill DataTable From SQL Query
da.Fill(dt)
```

The above block, modify the sqlCommand variable to include the following Columns

```
INSURED_FIRST_NAME + ' ' + INSURED_LAST_NAME AS RECIPIENT, PAYOR_FIRST_NAME + ' ' + PAYOR_LAST_NAME AS PURCHASER
```

Remove the following block alltogether

```vb
' Merge Columns
dt.Columns.Add("RECIPIENT", GetType(String)).SetOrdinal(0)
dt.Columns.Add("PURCHASER", GetType(String)).SetOrdinal(1)
For Each Row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Row("RECIPIENT") = String.Format("{0} {1}", Trim(Row("INSURED_FIRST_NAME")), Trim(Row("INSURED_LAST_NAME")))
    Row("PURCHASER") = String.Format("{0} {1}", Trim(Row("PAYOR_FIRST_NAME")), Trim(Row("PAYOR_LAST_NAME")))
Next
```

The following block isnt doing what you think, by default "AutoGenerateColumns" is true on DGV, also it is only relevant prior to setting the datasource.

```vb
' Add DataTable as DataSource and Auto Generate Columns
dgvContent.DataSource = Records
dgvContent.AutoGenerateColumns = True
```